# Slow clustered index seek on range compared to exact match (inaccurate cardinality estimate)

Tags: sql-server, indexing, large-data, sqlperformance

**Question:**
Can I somehow hint SQL Server on expected number of rows returned from index seek?

**Background:**

I have a unique clustered index:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T] ADD  CONSTRAINT [X] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Int1] ASC,
    [Int2] ASC,
    [Int3] ASC,
    [Int4] ASC
)
```

Now I have a query that fetches particular single value:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM [dbo].[T]
WHERE
    [Int1] = @Int1 AND
    [Int2] = @Int2 AND
    [Int3] = @Int3 AND
    [Int4] = @Int4
```

This runs instantaneously. With any values for arguments @Int1-4

Now I actually want a range of values.
If I iterate with cycle with increasing value of @Int4 (yes - something that's sounds completely wrong to do in SQL) - I get my results instantaneously.

```
-- Looks completely wrong for SQL - but it seems to be fastest way to fetch range of values
DECLARE @I INT = 1
WHILE @I <= 50
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM [dbo].[T]
    WHERE
        [Int1] = @Int1 AND
        [Int2] = @Int2 AND
        [Int3] = @Int3 AND
        [Int4] = @I

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
GO
```

If I specify the last condition as range:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM [dbo].[T]
WHERE
    [Int1] = @Int1 AND
    [Int2] = @Int2 AND
    [Int3] = @Int3 AND
    [Int4] BETWEEN @Int4 AND (@Int4 + 2)
```

The query takes minutes.
Same happens if I omit the [Int4] constraint altogether.

In all 3 cases the actual execution plan looks the same (clustered index seek):

[image: Actual Execution Plan]

The difference is in estimated vs actual rows returned. In case of exact condition it's both 1. In case of between or omitted condition it's a huge difference:

[image: Execution Plan Analysis]

Why is the difference in estimate hurting the performance so badly?
Is there any way how can I make the between or omitted condition run more quicker? Any way how to hint SQL that number of rows will be very low?

Btw. the table contains 73 billion rows. Data size is ~ 1.7TB and index size 4.2TB.
It can probably be rebuild, however it would require huge downtime. Plus I can make the query lightening fast if I just switch to dummy cycle.

**EDIT1:**

As requested - here is the actual DDL for table and indexes (first 4 columns are the INT1-INT4 in my simplified example above):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RelationalResultValueVectorial](
    [RelationalResultRowId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RelationalResultPropertyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RelationalResultVectorialDimensionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrdinalRowIdWithinProperty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RelationalResultValueId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Idx_RelationalResultValueVectorial] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RelationalResultRowId] ASC,
    [RelationalResultPropertyId] ASC,
    [RelationalResultVectorialDimensionId] ASC,
    [OrdinalRowIdWithinProperty] ASC
) ON [RelationalDataFileGroup]
) ON [RelationalDataFileGroup]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RelationalResultValueVectorial_ValueId] ON [dbo].[RelationalResultValueVectorial]
(
    [RelationalResultValueId] ASC
) ON [RelationalDataFileGroup]
GO

-- + some FKs
```

**EDIT2:**

As to the answer about parameters sniffing - here is what I get if I use solely constants (still wrong estimate and still very slow execution):

[image]

Comment: update statistics? reorg index? avoid `=>, <=` with `Int4 in (@Int4, @Int4 + 1, @Int4 + 2)` ?

Comment: The `Int4 IN (1,2,3)` runs for ages and have to completely wrong estimate as well (which is very strange). Index reorganize - yeah, it never hurts. But it still is not targeting the rootcause (difference in estimate and resulting increase in query time). Statistics - I checked and it is very recent (probably updated with long running query)

Comment: Can you post the table DDL and indexes?  You can probably even accomplish this with statistics on (Int1,Int2, Int3).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Interesting - the stats you suggested seem to make it quick now, althought the estimate is still way off. Is that OK and expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `variables`, and they are not "sniffed" in the query as it's written above.

In case of single values for every of your 4 fields composing `primary key`, knowing of these values is not needed, as server knows that every combination of these 4 fields is unique.

The thing is different when you use the condition `[Int4] BETWEEN @Int4 AND (@Int4 + 2)`. The result set cardinality may vary, you can specify the range of 1 value or all the values possible for `@int4`, and I repeat, if you don't ask your server to evaluate your expression/variables by using `optin(recompile)`, server will estimate the cardinality of `between` as 9% of rows (16% starting with `sql server 2014`).

Try to substitute your variables with `constants` and cardinality estimation will be based on the `statistics`, now it estimates it as for "unknown values".

So, the solution for your case is `recompile` option.

Comment: It's completely same story with the constants as well. `AND INT4 BETWEEN 1 AND 3` or `AND INT4 IN (1,2,3)` still produces execution plan with huge estimation. It however cannot be the mentioned 9% or 16% percent - as the table has some 73billions of rows and it estimates the query will fetch some 100k rows

Comment: >>>It however cannot be the mentioned 9% or 16% percent <<< I gave you the cardinality estimation for only ONE condition in predicate, but you have 4 (FOUR) conditions. The estimation of the whole predicate with AND conditions has different formulas for different optimizer versions. If you publish your server version and database compatibility level, or at least attach the plan and not a picture, I'll calculate the exact estimation for your case

Comment: Based on your comment I started looking into xmls of execution plan. I actually found out that wast majority of time was spent by compilation of the query. When querying clustered index an all of it's columns, the StatementOptmLevel changed from FULL to TRIVIAL and compilation cost was slashed. I also had to make other tweaks (SELECT instead of SET; GOTO instead of WHILE) to keep all statements in my query in TRIVIAL otpimization level and then the compilation and entire runtime of the query was lightening fast